# Modify the original array inside _.reject

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a way to modify the original array inside an _.reject?

I've tried the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1988/LS384/953/

```
var section = {
    rows: [
    {name:"Alejandro", $initialized: true},
    {name:"Benito", $initialized: false},
    {name:"Chinea", $initialized: true},
    {name:"Domingo", $initialized: true},
    {name:"Eduardo", $initialized: false},
    {name:"Yolanda", $initialized: true},
    {name:"Zacarias", $initialized: true}
  ]
};

section.rows = _.reject(section.rows, function(row, index, sectionRows){ 
  if (!row.$initialized) {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    sectionRows[index] = { test: "test" };
    return false;
  }
});

console.dir(section.rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is modifying the values in the original array, but then you overwrite the original array with the return value of `_.reject`. Remove the `section.rows =` and you'll see the modified values.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeps9nfu/)